# Unable to save settings in Firefox when installed as snap package?

Tags: firefox, snap, configuration, 22.04

I have just done a fresh install on a notebook with Xubuntu 22.04 as host OS. I've noticed that Firefox is now available only through `snap` unless you want to follow a lengthy tutorial on adding the PPA for it.

That's all fine and dandy but I noticed that I am unable to settings in Firefox. I am unable to do basic configuration such as restoring tabs upon startup as well as make Firefox check upon starts whether it is default browser or not. Speaking of default browser the button to make Firefox the default one it appears it too is not working.

The issue is not present when using the [PPA version from mozillateam](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Is this intentional? I hope that the `snap` version doesn't require users to edit text files somewhere on the system...

Comment: You cannot set the snap and flatpak versions of Firefox as default browser. I can restore earlier session in the flatpak on 20.04 though ( setting -->general -->restore earlier session.  Can't you do that in the snap of 22.04?

Comment: report the issue to mozzila https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox

Comment: @JoepieEs Firefox is still the default browser in Ubuntu 22.04 and it's a snap. You can change the preference to another browser as default and back to Firefox. I don't know where you got that idea from...

Comment: @ChanganAuto In Firefox itself the option is not available. That is what I'm talking about. Of course the snap is the browser that comes with 22.04 and is the default browser.